# NestJS Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RolesService (+, +, ?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, dependencies, nestjs

Hi I'm programming using the NestJS framework (with MongoDB) and have build some modules now. When I try to import a model from another module it returns this error:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RolesService (+, +, ?).

Now, I've implemented the code like this:

app.module.ts

```
import { GroupsModule } from './groups/groups.module';
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { UsersModule } from 'users/users.module';
import { RolesModule } from 'roles/roles.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
          MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost:27017/example'),
          UsersModule,
          GroupsModule,
          RolesModule,
        ],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

users.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

import { UsersController } from './users.controller';

import { UsersService } from './users.service';
import { RolesService } from 'roles/roles.service';

import { UserSchema } from './schemas/user.schema';
import { RoleSchema } from 'roles/schemas/role.schema';

@Module({
    imports: [
      MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'User', schema: UserSchema }]),
      MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Role', schema: RoleSchema }]),
    ],
    controllers: [UsersController],
    providers: [UsersService, RolesService],
    exports: [UsersService],
  })

export class UsersModule {}
```

users.service.ts

```
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { ObjectID } from 'mongodb';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Injectable, HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';

import { User } from './interfaces/user.interface';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(@InjectModel('User') private readonly userModel: Model<User>) {}
}
```

groups.module.ts

```
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

import { GroupsController } from './groups.controller';

import { RolesService } from '../roles/roles.service';
import { GroupsService } from './groups.service';

import { GroupSchema } from './schemas/group.schema';
import { UserSchema } from '../users/schemas/user.schema';
import { RoleSchema } from '../roles/schemas/role.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Group', schema: GroupSchema }]),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'User', schema: UserSchema }]),
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Role', schema: RoleSchema }]),
  ],
  controllers: [GroupsController],
  providers: [GroupsService, RolesService],
  exports: [GroupsService],
})
```

groups.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ObjectID } from 'mongodb';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';

import { Group } from './interfaces/group.interface';
import { User } from '../users/interfaces/user.interface';

import { CreateGroupDto } from './dto/create-group.dto';
import { RolesDto } from 'roles/dto/roles.dto';
import { Role } from '../roles/interfaces/role.interface';

@Injectable()
export class GroupsService {
    constructor(@InjectModel('Group') private readonly groupModel: Model<Group>,
                @InjectModel('Role') private readonly roleModel: Model<Role>) {} }
```

roles.module.ts

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

import { RolesController } from './roles.controller';

import { RolesService } from './roles.service';

import { RoleSchema } from './schemas/role.schema';
import { UserSchema } from '../users/schemas/user.schema';
import { GroupSchema } from '../groups/schemas/group.schema';

@Module({
    imports: [
      MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'User', schema: UserSchema }]),
      MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Role', schema: RoleSchema }]),
      MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Group', schema: GroupSchema }]),
    ],
    controllers: [RolesController],
    providers: [RolesService],
    exports: [RolesService],
  })

export class RolesModule {}
```

roles.service.ts

```
import { Injectable, HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { ObjectID } from 'mongodb';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';

import { Role } from './interfaces/role.interface';
import { User } from '../users/interfaces/user.interface';
import { Group } from '../groups/interfaces/group.interface';

import { CreateRoleDto } from './dto/create-role.dto';
import { RolesDto } from './dto/roles.dto';

@Injectable()
export class RolesService {
    constructor( @InjectModel('Role') private readonly roleModel: Model<Role>,
                 @InjectModel('User') private readonly userModel: Model<User>,
                 @InjectModel('Group') private readonly groupModel: Model<Group> ) {} }
```

While the DI in the users and roles works fine, the error arise when I try to import the Group Model in the roles service. Please tell me if you see anything wrong, I've follow the same schema from users with groups but unfortunately can't see where the error lives.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: OK I think my error is when I try to use a module service function outside the module. I mean I modified (in order to simplify) I'll modify the code this way:

users.module.ts

```
@Module({
    imports: [
      MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'User', schema: UserSchema }]),
      RolesModule,
    ],
    controllers: [UsersController],
    providers: [UsersService, RolesService],
    exports: [UsersService],
  })

export class UsersModule {}
```

users.controller.ts

```
export class UsersController {

    constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService,
                private readonly rolesService: RolesService){}

    async addRoles(@Param('id') id: string, @Body() userRolesDto: UserRolesDto): Promise<User> {
        try {
            return this.rolesService.setRoles(id, userRolesDto);
        } catch (e){
            const message = e.message.message;
            if ( e.message.error === 'NOT_FOUND'){
                throw new NotFoundException(message);
            } else if ( e.message.error === 'ID_NOT_VALID'){
                throw new BadRequestException(message);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

roles.module.ts

```
@Module({
    imports: [
      MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Role', schema: RoleSchema }]),
    ],
    controllers: [RolesController],
    providers: [RolesService],
    exports: [RolesService],
  })

export class RolesModule {}
```

roles.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class RolesService {
    userModel: any;
    constructor( @InjectModel('Role') private readonly roleModel: Model<Role> ) {}

    // SET USER ROLES
    async setRoles(id: string, rolesDto: RolesDto): Promise<User> {
        if ( !ObjectID.isValid(id) ){
            throw new HttpException({error: 'ID_NOT_VALID', message: `ID ${id} is not valid`, status: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST}, 400);
        }
        try {
            const date = moment().valueOf();
            const resp = await this.userModel.updateOne({
              _id: id,
            }, {
              $set: {
                  updated_at: date,
                  roles: rolesDto.roles,
              },
            });
            if ( resp.nModified === 0 ){
              throw new HttpException({ error: 'NOT_FOUND', message: `ID ${id} not found or entity not modified`, status: HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND}, 404);
            } else {
              let user = await this.userModel.findOne({ _id: id });
              user = _.pick(user, ['_id', 'email', 'roles', 'created_at', 'updated_at']);
              return user;
            }
        } catch (e) {
          if ( e.message.error === 'NOT_FOUND' ){
            throw new HttpException({ error: 'NOT_FOUND', message: `ID ${id} not found or entity not modified`, status: HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND}, 404);
          } else {
            throw new HttpException({error: 'ID_NOT_VALID', message: `ID ${id} is not valid`, status: HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST}, 400);
          }
        }
    }
```

That's it, as you can see when I try to use from users.controller the roles.service setRole method it returns me an error:

Nest can't resolve dependencies of the RolesService (?). Please make sure that the argument at index [0]is available in the current context.

I don't understand where the problem is because I'm injecting the Role model in the roles.module already and it don't understand it. In fact if I don't create the call from users.module to this dependency everything goes fine.

Any tip?

(I've red the suggestion from stackoverflow, I'll don't do it again)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're importing the same model multiple times, like:

```
MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'User', schema: UserSchema }]
```

and also providing the same service multiple times:

```
providers: [RolesService]
```

I would not inject the models themselves but rather the corresponding services that encapsulate the model. Then you `export` the service in its module and import the module where needed. So the `RolesService` would inject the `UsersSerivce` instead of the `UserModel`.

With your current setup, you would run into circular dependencies though. This can be handled with `fowardRef(() => UserService)` but should be avoided if possible, see the [circular dependency docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/circular-dependency). If this is avoidable depends on your business logic however.

If you don't have circular dependencies then for example export your `RolesService`

```
@Module({
    imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'Role', schema: RoleSchema }])]
    controllers: [RolesController],
    providers: [RolesService],
    exports: [RolesService],
  })

export class RolesModule {}
```

and import the `RolesModule` wherever you want to use the `RolesService`, e.g.:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
      RolesModule,
      MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: 'User', schema: UserSchema }])
    ],
    controllers: [UsersController],
    providers: [UsersService],
    exports: [UsersService],
  })
```

Comment: Thanks Kim, I've been trying to do what you comment but unfortunately I couldn't find the solution. I did try to call the line you comment just once and call it from the module where it's needed (RolesService for example). In this case if you can tell me how to implement it, should be very helpful. I'm not going to use circular-dependency, I've red a lot of docs but couldn't find the solution ... (little desperate by now)

Comment: It's very hard to tell how you should implement it because I don't what you want to implement. I can only assume, that you want to check if a user has a certain role. You can check out the [RolesGuard example](https://docs.nestjs.com/guards) in the docs. In this case they attach the roles to the authorized user in the response (e.g. from a JWT).

Comment: Hi Kim again thanks for your answers, sorry but I can't understand the way DI works (i've read a millions of times the docs). But it works for me in some cases and other not. Specifically when I import a module from another module it seems to not recognize the stuff imported by itself. Sorry, a little bit confusing my requirement maybe ... I found nestjs a great framework but a little bit "misty" in this sense (or maybe is my lack of understanding about it) Thanks anyway

Comment: When you import a module it will only import the exported providers. If you update your code in your question, I'll have a look at it again. Also consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :-)

Comment: Remove the RolesService from the UserModule's providers array. You're importing the module and with that all its exported providers. If you provide the RolesService again, it will look for its dependcies (the Roles model) and not find it in the UsersModule.

Comment: AWESOME, a newbie error from my part, it works indeed. Just one more question, can I use just Roles Service calling it from providers without import RolesModule?

Comment: Great, I'm glad it works now. :-) If you think my answer was helpful, you can accept/upvote it. - No, you have to import the RolesModule. (Except within the RolesModule itself, here you can use it e.g. in the RolesController.)